# clang --version permission denied error

Tags: c++, command-line, clang, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed the latest `clang-6.0` using the instructions from here:
[`install latest clang (6.0) on Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) / WSL`](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/k/how-to-install-latest-clang-6.0-on-ubuntu-16.04-xenial-wsl.html). Basically, these are the steps:

```sh
wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-6.0 main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y clang-6.0
```

---

It was successful but while checking for the version I'm getting the following error

```sh
 ❯ clang --version 
 ⏎
zsh: permission denied: clang
```

What's the issue here and how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm sure this is on topic here since it's about tools primarily used for programming, but you may want to ask on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) instead since this is likely an OS level issue.

Comment: Yes, I see this as a command-line issue; although, `g++ --version` works perfectly fine, I'm not sure what's wrong here when using `clang --version`

Comment: Can you add the output for `which clang` and `ls -lh $(which clang)`?  I just tried this in a docker container and everything worked fine even with a non-root user and zsh.

Comment: Do you have the same problem using another shell (bash or whatever, but not zsh)?

Comment: I'm getting `clang not found` for `which clang`; and for the latter I get: `ls: cannot access 'clang': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'not': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'found': No such file or directory
`

Comment: Then clang isn't actually installed.  Could you run `apt-get install clang` again?  I did see that `which clang` failed the first time I ran it, but I thought I had accidentally forgot to actually install clang.  That may actually be important to sorting this.

Comment: Sorry, I see that it says it's installed: `sudo apt-get install clang-6.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
clang-6.0 is already the newest version (1:6.0.1~svn333623-1~exp1~20180604222746.83).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
`

Comment: Then try `clang-6.0 --version` or install without the version `apt-get install clang` (without the `-6.0`).

Comment: Oops! That works :) Actually, doing `sudo apt-get install clang` installs version 3.8 which is old. That's why I installed `clang-6.0` explicitly. how do I symlink `clang-6.0` to `clang` ? btw, would you like to post this as an answer? I'd be glad to accept it!

Comment: I had the wrong ubuntu which is why it was still installing 6 by default.  I'm still looking for the appropriate way to say `clang` should point to `clang-6.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are installing, the clang binary is being installed at `/usr/bin/clang-6.0`.  However, you are trying to run `clang --version`.  This is likely to avoid clobbering in case you have multiple versions of clang installed.

You have 2 options:

1. Install clang without the version, `apt-get install clang`, which should still install clang 6 since it is in your package list.
2. Use the binary by the correct name, `clang-6.0 --version`

I tested this out using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# Install software we need to test
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    wget \
    zsh

# Get clang-6.0 package
RUN wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | apt-key add - && \
    apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/xenial/ llvm-toolchain-xenial-6.0 main"

# Install clang-6.0 package
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    clang-6.0

# Default to shell
ENTRYPOINT ["zsh"]
```

I get the output:

```sh
# which clang
clang not found
# which clang-6.0
/usr/bin/clang-6.0
```